# Having issue with regex expression in python

Tags: python

I have following output from open source tool "cloc". I want to use python regex expression to grab all items in Languages column.

```sh
$ cloc .
       6 text files.
       6 unique files.                              
       3 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.80  T=0.02 s (238.3 files/s, 34909.8 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python                           1             46            110            347
Markdown                         1              8              0             35
Dockerfile                       1              6              0             19
YAML                             1              0              0             15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                             4             60            110            416
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using following code but no luck so far.

```py
class Cloc():
    def cloc_scan(self, dir_path=None):
        if dir_path is not None:
            cmd = 'cloc {}'.format(dir_path)
            returncode, stdout, stderr = util.run_command(
                cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            if returncode != 0:
                logger.debug_error = "returncode is {returncode}\nstdout:\n{stdout}".format(
                    returncode=returncode, stdout=stdout)
                raise Exception(logger.debug_error)
            else:
                logger.debug("Cloc scan successful.")
                if stdout:
                    matches = []
                    for line in stdout.splitlines():
                        regex = r"^([^ \t \n \- \gLS]+)"
                        match = re.findall(regex, line)
                        matches.append(match)
                        if line:
                            if line[:1] == "[":
                                logger.debug("{line}".format(line=line))
                            else:
                                logger.debug("{line}".format(line=line))
                    languages = [x for x in matches if x]
                    languages = [item for sublist in languages for item in sublist]
                    logger.info(languages)
                    logger.info(stdout)
                    return stdout
        else:
            logger.info("Unable to run scan without path to source code directory")
```

Comment: Actually, what is your problem? Is it about the RegEx?

Answer (score 1):

So you can make your life easier by making the results out of cloc come out much cleaner if you do this:

```
cloc ./my_repo_here/  --csv --quiet | tail -n +3 | cut -d ',' -f 2
```

Which yields these results:

```
Python
Markdown
Dockerfile
YAML
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` to split each line with the white-space as a delimiter.

For instance, if *content* is the content of STDOUT, you can do:

```py
>>> import re
>>> for line in content.splitlines():
...     print(re.split(r'\s+', line))
...
```

The result is something like this:

```py
['']
['', '6', 'text', 'files.']
['', '6', 'unique', 'files.', '']
['', '3', 'files', 'ignored.']
['']
['github.com/AlDanial/cloc', 'v', '1.80', 'T=0.02', 's', '(238.3', 'files/s,', '34909.8', 'lines/s)']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
['Language', 'files', 'blank', 'comment', 'code']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
['Python', '1', '46', '110', '347']
['Markdown', '1', '8', '0', '35']
['Dockerfile', '1', '6', '0', '19']
['YAML', '1', '0', '0', '15']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
['SUM:', '4', '60', '110', '416']
['-------------------------------------------------------------------------------']
```